# Make duplicates real? Blender 2.93

Tags: modeling, modifiers

"make duplicates real" does No longer exist in Blender 2.93?

There are alternative solutions to make duplicates to Single objects?

Comment: I think it's make instances real now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That depends on how you created your duplicates.

1. If you created a 2.79 (and early?) [*dupliverts*](https://docs.blender.org/manual/es/2.79/editors/3dview/object/properties/duplication/dupliverts.html), then you would have had the option to "make duplicates real" available.  In 2.9x, dupliverts have been replaced [*Instancing*](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/scene_layout/object/properties/instancing/index.html), and the equivalent operation is "make instance real". It has the short cut <kbd>CTRL</kbd>–<kbd>A</kbd> and select "Make instances real" from the menu:

[image: Apply menu showing Make instances real option]

I believe Blender automatically converts old dupliverts into new instancing.

2. If you created the duplicates by creating an array, you *apply* the array modifier, then in edit mode select and use <kbd>P</kbd> to separate the parts by selection.  If each object is a single mesh, you can select all and separate by loose parts.
3. If you created the duplicates by using [*Duplicate Linked*](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/scene_layout/object/editing/duplicate_linked.html) then you separate the duplicate by making it single user, most easily done through the Object menu:

[image: Object menu showing Make Single User options]

4. Finally, if you created the duplicates by linking from a library you separate the duplicate by [*making it local*](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/files/linked_libraries/link_append.html#make-local), most easily done through the Object menu:

[image: Object menu showing Make Local options]

Comment: Wow. Big thanks.